# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException Timeout Expired c#

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures, timeoutexception

i'm getting error

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException Timeout Expired

in this in MySqlReader

My code

```
public MySqlReader(MySqlCommand command)
        {
            if (command.Type == MySqlCommandType.SELECT)
            {
                _dataset = new DataSet();
                _row = 0;
                using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn = DataHolder.MySqlConnection)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (var DataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command.Command, conn))
                        DataAdapter.Fill(_dataset, Table);
                    ((IDisposable)command).Dispose();  // in this line
                }
            }
        }
```

What can i do to fix this?

Full error:

> [04:46:58] MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Timeout
>   expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
>   operation or the server i s not responding. --->
>   System.TimeoutException: A connection attempt failed beca use the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   esta blished connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond ---> Syst em.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the
>   transport connection: A connecti on attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a p eriod of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has faile d to
>   respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt
>   fail ed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 s ize)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 s ize)    at MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 count)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   MyNetworkStream.HandleOrRethrowException(Exception e)    at
>   MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32  count)    at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[]
>   buffer,  Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow,
>   Int32& i nsertedId)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior )    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.HandleTimeoutOrThreadAbort(Exceptio
>   n ex)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior )    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   be havior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandB
>   ehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[]  datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand co mmand, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)
>
> at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String
>   srcTable)    at DeadPool.Database.MySqlReader..ctor(MySqlCommand
>   command) in C:\Users\Admi
>   nistrator\Desktop\NewSource\Source\Database\MySql\MySqlReader.cs:line
>   26    at DeadPool.Database.SkillTable.LoadSpells(GameState client) in
>   C:\Users\Admi
>   nistrator\Desktop\NewSource\Source\Database\SkillTable.cs:line 161
>   at DeadPool.Database.SkillTable.LoadSpells(GameState client,
>   MySqlConnection conn) in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewSource\Source\Database\SkillTable.cs:
>   line 184    at DeadPool.Client.GameState.LoadData(Boolean loadFake) in
>   C:\Users\Administr
>   ator\Desktop\NewSource\Source\Client\GameState.cs:line 6290    at
>   DeadPool.Network.PacketHandler.DoLogin(GameState client) in
>   C:\Users\Admin
>   istrator\Desktop\NewSource\Source\Network\PacketHandler.cs:line 27490 
>   at DeadPool.Network.PacketHandler.AppendConnect(Connect appendConnect,
>   GameSt ate client) in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewSource\Source\Network\PacketHan
>   dler.cs:line 27434    at
>   DeadPool.Network.PacketHandler.HandlePacket(Byte[] packet, GameState
>   clien t) in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewSource\Source\Network\PacketHandler.cs:l
>   ine 2494    at DeadPool.Program.processData(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   length, GameState Client ) in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewSource\Source\Program.cs:line 1353
>   at DeadPool.Program.GameServer_OnClientReceive(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   length, C lientWrapper obj) in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\NewSource\Source\Program.cs: line 1336 
>   at DeadPool.Network.Sockets.ClientWrapper.doReceive(Int32 available)
>   in C:\Us
>   ers\Administrator\Desktop\NewSource\Source\Network\Sockets\ClientWrapper.cs:line
>   121

Comment: Is it caused by data volume or network connectivity? What is expected timeout?

Comment: Updated and added full error @qxg

Comment: My bet is on some network issue. Wrong server/DB name, blocked port, etc.

Comment: tell me what can i do to fix this error please?

Comment: Check your connection string and make sure server name, database name and port is correct. Make sure the account you're using has proper credentials.

Comment: If you carefully check the error then it means the connection was opened successfully but it could not finish the command succesfuly due to timeout. Try increasing timeout using `CommandTimeout` property. That should sove your problem

Answer (score 0):

Increase the time out by setting the command object property: `CommandTimeout`.  I believe the default value is 30 (in seconds).

So, your updated method:

```
public MySqlReader(MySqlCommand command)
{
    //HERE!!!!
    command.CommandTimeout = 60;

    if (command.Type == MySqlCommandType.SELECT)
    {
         _dataset = new DataSet();
         _row = 0;
         using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn = 
             DataHolder.MySqlConnection)
         {
             conn.Open();
             using (var DataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command.Command, conn))
                  DataAdapter.Fill(_dataset, Table);
                 ((IDisposable)command).Dispose();  // in this line
        }
    }
}
```